# Can we set user permission to create a file but not a subdirectory in a directory?

Tags: files, permissions, directory

Is it possible to give permission to only create files but not a directory to a user in linux?

```
abc@xyz:~/temp$ touch a
abc@xyz:~/temp$ mkdir b
abc@xyz:~/temp$
```

I want `mkdir b` to fail but `touch a` to succeed.

Comment: AFAIK all in UNIX/Linux is file so creation of file do not differ so much from creating directory

Comment: I don't think this is possible.

Comment: There are methods but they are rather messy and tedious to manage: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/78191/prevent-creating-directories-but-allow-creating-files.